# fetch nested object from array in JavaScript?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, react-chartjs

I have data like that

```
const Power = [
    {
    "Week": [
      {"x": "Monday", "y": 11},
      {"x": "Tuseday", "y": 12},
      {"x": "Wednesday", "y": 17},
      {"x": "Thursday", "y": 18},
      {"x": "Friday", "y": 19},
      {"x": "Saturday", "y": 18},
      {"x": "Sunday", "y": 11}
    ],
    "Days": [
      {"x": "6:00 am", "y": 18},
      {"x": "10:00 am", "y": 13},
      {"x": "2:00 pm", "y": 16},
      {"x": "4:00 pm", "y": 14},
      {"x": "8:00 pm", "y": 19},
      {"x": "11:00 pm", "y": 13}
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to design the chart by different data by Days and Week so, I unable to fetch the data by week and Days individually. So, Please suggest some solutions to achieve this

Comment: Have you tried anything? what should be the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

try yo look on chartjs and react-chartjs-2(you need to download chartjs for this)
you need to make array of the x and y axis and send it in a object

```
 {
  labels: string[];
  datasets: {
    label: string;
    backgroundColor?: string;
    borderColor: string;
    pointBackgroundColor?: string;
    data: number[]
  }[]
}
```

I keep the types from my typescript project so you can see how you can send it